# Is it possible in theory to use dark energy to do work?

Tags: energy, work, space-expansion, dark-energy

Discounting the sheer size of the machine you'd need (millions of light years) and the lightspeed delay in operating it. Just the bare question: if dark energy accelerates expansion, is there any conceivable way of using this to do work?

Comment: You're assuming that dark energy is real.  To date, it is only a hypothesis (aka speculation).

Answer (score -1):

I think so. If you put a mega super-material network around a faraway galaxy, connect the super-material net with a long rope to Earth, what will happen? The rope will snap. But we could decelerate it with special gears. We cannot let the Earth be pulled out of orbit. What can we do with the rope that pulls? It would be a nice question to calculate the force! But it must be huge. It will be difficult to do something with the rope, despite it delivering a tremendous force. If we tie it to Earth, bye bye Earth. If not, what then? If we use pulleys to change the direction of the force 90 degrees, so the force becomes parallel to Earth there will still be a pull on the Earth's orbit. This will be the case for every Earth-based construction. It's difficult! Let the rope carry weight up which we throw back for kinetic energy? Let the rope develop friction? The acceleration of the rope will be (almost) constant, whatever contra-force we apply. And the rope must be very long. Forget it...

Comment: I appreciate your effort but this answer is too freewheeling for me to really tell if you are answering yes or no.